# memory limit exceed in building form in symfony

Tags: symfony

I build a form, for a CRUD view.

In this form I have build a `<select>` relationed to an Entity that have LONGBLOB fields.

When I build the object, the app exploit with a max memory limit problem.

How, when I am buiding the form, tell it that from the Entity B, only take id, an name.

Comment: Just to point out that there must be a better way to do this, by you not storing your LONGBLOB in your database. Just store the url of the file on your server instead. This way your database access will be greatly lightened.

Comment: ok thans, this is not the solution that i looking for but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of “incomplete” entities, you can force *partial loading*:

```
$result = $entityManager
    ->createQuery('SELECT partial EntityB.{id,name} FROM YourSomethingBundle:EntityB EntityB')
    ->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true)
    ->getResult();
```

Be sure to read the [documentation on partial loading](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html#what-is-the-problem), because it has some implications.